# Reference .net461 assembly from netstandard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

According to [Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/)("Reference .NET Framework libraries from .NET Standard") we can reference full framework libraries <= .NET 4.6.1 from .NetStandard 2.0 projects to help with the migration of existing code starting with Visual Studio 15.3

So why does the following not work?

NetStandard/NetStandard.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FullFramework\FullFramework.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

FullFramework/FullFramework.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Gives me the following error:

```
  error NU1201: Project FullFramework is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project FullFramework supports: net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1)
  error : Project '..\FullFramework\FullFramework.csproj' targets 'net461'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'.
```

Comment: The `NetStandard` project is portable meaning it can be used in a Linux or Mac box. What do you think it would do when it tries to reference a class library that only targets .Net 4.6.1?

Comment: It works if you reference project with "old" csproj format. Makes some sense (but not too much) since that's feature mostly to port old code, where "new" csproj format did not exist anyway. Also works if you reference .dll directly (for that case it of course doesn't matter which csproj was used).

Comment: @Evk Oh it works indeed. I converted the projects automatically because the new csproj + PackageReference is awesome (yes I know I can use it with the old format too, but I don't get the awesome new separation into nuget, projects, etc.). It makes sense and it's not a big problem to keep the old format, but I don't understand that limitation.

Comment: On trying it out it's actually a bit worse than that: You can't use the new PackageReference feature either if you don't want to see the compile error (this makes sense to a degree considering the differences between packages.config and PackageReference in referenced projects). Would you convert your comment to an answer so we can close the question? I'll throw in a bit of extra rep if I don't forget too, although I guess you don't care much about that either any more :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature works if you reference projects which use "old" .csproj format (and target .NET 4.6.1 or less), or it you reference library (.dll file) directly, but for unknown (for me) reason - doesn't work if you reference project with .csproj in "new" format (like in your question). One can argue that because this feature goal is to enable easier porting of old code - it makes some sense that projects in new format are not supported, thought I suppose it's more an oversight than intentional.